# Find absolute maximum of $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2$ within square $0\le x ,y\le 1$ (long but interesting)

Tags: calculus, optimization

---

Notice:

*"***There is another possible and common interpretation for 0≤x,y≤1, namely 0≤x∧y≤1. Hence the OP's references to the infinite.*** – Git Gud"

*If anyone ever stumbles upon this post in the future, and wonders what this post is all about...the above pretty much sums it up.
Confused 0≤x,y≤1, with 0≤x∧y≤1.
Nevertheless, I've gained from this by learning not to put both partial derivatives equal to each other and that it was possible to treat both x and y as independent.
Case closed :)**

---

**strong text**Background:
This problem is part of a list given to us in order to prepare for the final multivariable calculus exam. It's not a honours course, so I suspect a few of the problems(such as this one!) on the list are intended to be difficult in order to "calibrate" the class average. The problems on the list will closely mirror those on the exam.

---

First of all, I began setting the partial derivatives equal to zero to find critical points.

$$f'_x=2x-2, f'_y=2y-4$$
I set $f'_y=f'_x, 2x-2=2y-4\dots$.it gives the critical point $(0,1)$.

Then I used the $D(a,b)$ formula and found that $(0,1)$ corresponds to a local **minimum** point, $f(x,y)=2$ or $(0,1,2)$.

---

I used a graphing tool and realized that the graph of $f(x,y)$ represents an ellipsoid, which, as far as I know, has no absolute maximum on an unbounded domain. 
The problem states that $f(x,y)$ is bounded by a square $0\le x, y\le 1$.

After some thinking, I realized that since the "square" was bounded by $y=1$ and $x=0$, it made the situation complicated because it did not represent a "square" of finite proportions. Another problem is that $0\le x, y\le 1$ can also represent a rectangle...

I tried to think of a function that could "act" as a constraint which would limit the domain to a set of points which represented a family of squares, such as y=-x+1 which would generate points which make the domain square-shaped.

For example: $0\le x, y\le 1$, gives $(0,1)$ and with the function ${y=-x+1|0\le x,y\le 1}$, I can generate points such as $(1,0), (2,-1),\dots,(x,-x+1),$ which give squares when paired with point $(0,1)$.

But since the problem asks for **the** Absolute Maximum, I realized that depending on which point I used, I would get a different "Absolute Maximum" represented by a contour line of the ellipsoid depending on the size of the square I take as a domain.

First of all, I'm not even sure if my approach is mathematically correct.
Secondly, I'm confused about the definition of "Absolute maximum"...

wikipedia: "The function $\cos(x)$ has infinitely many global maxima at $0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi, \dots,$ and infinitely many global minima at $\pm \pi, \pm 3\pi, \dots$." I understand this.

But in the case of this problem, can I say that the family of squares defined by constraints ${y=-x+1|0\le x,y\le 1} ; 0\le x,; y\le 1,$ each give a different global maxima?(contour line of the ellipsoid.)

---

While not related to the question, a second problem arose...

Using wolfram, I found that the point $(1,1)$ gives the absolute minima. 
In class, we only saw the partial derivative and second derivative test method for finding critical points. What methods were used to find this?

Thank you!

Comment: Great question! Most people just stick a problem into your face and expect you to solve it when they wright their first question, but you actually put time and effort into this.

Comment: Please note the MathJAX edits to your post; specifically, the \$ delimiters which denote a mathematical expression.  Please double-check the result to make sure that your meaning and intent have been preserved by my edit.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've always been more of the forum lurker type. This is actually the first post I've made on a forum in years...but I'm glad I took the plunge tonight and registered!

Comment: @user145977 You didn't need to register to post, but it's good that you did. Your partial derivatives are wrong. Try again. Also you're setting $f'_x=f'_y$. That's not what you're supposed to do, you should set $f'_x=0\land f'_y=0$.

Comment: Thank you!I corrected it.[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize+%28x-1%29^2%2B%28y-2%29^2+on++y%3C%3D1+and+x%3E%3D0)    f′x=0...2x-2=0...x=1 and f′y=0...2y-4=0...y=2, so (x,y)=(1,2) but y≤1.

Comment: Sorry, did not have time to finish the post before 5 min limit. When I set both partial derivatives to 0, the point I get (1,2) is outside the domain.

Comment: @user145977 To address someone, precede your comment with `@ScreenName` so that person gets a notification. I only noticed you replied by mere chance. I see your problem has been dealt with by a new answer below.

Comment: @Git Gud Thank you! "There is another possible and common interpretation for 0≤x,y≤1, namely 0≤x∧y≤1. Hence the OP's references to the infinite". I apologize, I just noticed that my title was written in a way which could easily be mistaken for 0≤(x,y)≥1. In fact, I would probably have interpreted it that way as well if I had no prior knowledge of the problem. My apologies. Any suggestions on how to tackle the problem?

Comment: @user145977 I think you're misinterpreting the problem. In my opinion the set at hand is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon 0\leq x\leq 1\land 0\leq y\leq 1\}$.

Comment: If you want to use **strong text**, you should delimit the text by **, `**like this**`.

Comment: @Git Gud You know what? I read what you just wrote and went back to read the problem once more. You're probably right. Even though there were no (), the way the values are positioned makes it kind of obvious(for everyone except me!) that 0≤x,y≤1, means (0,1). if it had been 1≤x,y≤0, then it would have been open to interpretation. All along, I felt fascinated and inspired by this seemingly difficult problem while in reality what took hours of my life could have taken mere minutes had I been more careful. But then again, if I had read it right, I would have registered and I'm glad I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to take the partials, but you should not set them equal--you should set them simultaneously to $0$ (which you will find $x$ and $y$ are independent just as TonyK stated):

$$
2(x - 1) = 0 \rightarrow x = 1 \\
2(y - 2) = 0 \rightarrow y = 2
$$

This is the *only* critical point of the function $f(x, y)$ (and is outside of our region).  When finding absolute extrema, you have to test *all* critical points (unless you can argue they aren't local extrema) and *all* boundary points (this is what a lot of Calculus students forget to do).  You have four boundaries:

1. $x = 0, 0 \leq y \leq 1$
2. $x = 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1$
3. $y = 0, 0 \leq x \leq 1$
4. $y = 1, 0 \leq x \leq 1$

When you have a $1$-D function, the boundaries are single points.  When you have a $2$-D function, the boundaries are curves ($1$-D objects), if you have a $3$-D function, the boundaries are surfaces ($2$-D objects), so on and so forth.  So you have to now find the absolute extrema of four functions (the four boundaries--don't forget we'll need to test the endpoints, the boundaries, for each of those four functions):

$$
x = 0 \rightarrow f(0, y) = 1 + (y - 2)^2 \rightarrow f'(0, y) = 2(y -2) \rightarrow y = 2 \\
x = 1 \rightarrow f(1, y) = 0 + (y - 2)^2 \rightarrow f'(1, y) = 2(y - 2) \rightarrow y = 2 \\
y = 0 \rightarrow f(x, 0) = (x - 1)^2 + 4 \rightarrow f'(x,0) = 2(x - 1) \rightarrow x = 1 \\
y = 1 \rightarrow f(x, 1) = (x - 1)^2 + 1 \rightarrow f'(x, 1) = 2(x - 1) \rightarrow x = 1 \\
$$

The first two are outside of our region ($y = 2$) and the other two are corners of the square.  So we just need to test each corner of the square since all of our critical points are either outside of the region or on the corners (and the corners are the boundaries, or endpoints, of each of the boundary line segments):

$$
f(0, 0) = 1 + 4 = 5 \\
f(0, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2 \\
f(1, 0) = 0 + 4 = 4 \\
f(1, 1) = 0 + 1 = 1
$$

That's all of the critical points *and* all of the boundary points (which were the corners of the square), so the absolute minimum occurs at $(1, 1)$ and $f(1, 1) = 1$ and the absolute maximum occurs at $(0, 0)$ and $f(0, 0) = 5$.

The key is that when finding absolute extrema you cannot *only* test critical points you must *also* test the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I knew that I had to test the boundaries but I could not find what the boundaries were. "When you have a 1-D function, the boundaries are single points." that and the fact that I did not set x and y as independent is probably where my problem is. My brain is fried from too much thinking, I'll take a hour of rest and re-read carefully once I'm able to think clearly once more. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is much easier than you think! You can just maximise $(x-1)^2$ and $(y-2)^2$ independently, because the constraints for $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other. Specifically:

Let $M_x$ be the maximum of $(x-1)^2$ subject to $0 \le x \le 1$.
Let $M_y$ be the maximum of $(y-2)^2$ subject to $0 \le y \le 1$.

Then the maximum value of $f(x,y)$ is just $M_x + M_y$.

Hint: you don't need calculus to find $M_x$ and $M_y$!

Comment: Does 0≤x≤1 and 0≤y≤1 corresponds to the same domain as 0≤x,y≤1? Maximizing independently is a very good idea, I would never have thought of that on my own! Thank you

Comment: $0 \le x,y \le 1$ is just shorthand for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$. You yourself called it a square in the title!

Comment: There is another possible and common interpretation for $0 \le x,y \le 1$, namely $0 \le x\land y \le 1$. Hence the OP's references to the infinite.

Comment: That's exactly the part that confused me the most...The problem used the word square but the way I understand it is that 0≤x represents x=0 to infinity and y≤1 represents y=1 to minus infinity. I looked in stewarts to see if I could find a similar problem and all I did find was one with domain |y|≤1 and 0≤|x|, but it gives a square of finite dimension because of the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Lets $\ds{\quad{x \over y} = \sin\pars{\theta}\quad\mbox{with}\quad
      0 \leq \theta \leq \pi}$. The task is to find the maximum of
$\ds{\phi\pars{\theta,y} \equiv
     \bracks{y\sin\pars{\theta} - 1}^{2} + \pars{y - 2}^{2}}$

> $\ds{\partiald{\phi\pars{\theta,y}}{\theta} = 0}$ and $\ds{\partiald{\phi\pars{\theta,y}}{y} = 0}$ lead to:
>   \begin{align}
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
> \bracks{y\sin\pars{\theta} - 1}y\cos\pars{\theta} & = & 0
> \\[1mm]
> \bracks{y\sin\pars{\theta} - 1}\sin\pars{\theta} & = & 2 - y
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

1. $\ds{y\sin\pars{\theta} - 1 = 0\quad\imp\quad x = 1\,,\quad y = 2}$.
2. $\ds{y=0\quad\imp\quad\sin\pars{\theta} = -2}$ which doesn't have any sense.
3. $\ds{\cos\pars{\theta}=0\quad\imp\quad x=y={3 \over 2}}$.

> Solution $\ds{1.}$ yields the value $\ds{\fermi\pars{x=1,y=2} = 0}$
>   while solution $\ds{3.}$ yields the value
>   $\ds{\fermi\pars{x={3 \over 2},y={3 \over 2}} = \pars{{3 \over 2} - 1}^{2} + \pars{{3 \over 2} - 2}^{2} = \half}$

$${\tt Maximum}:\qquad
\color{#00f}{\large%
x = y = {3 \over 2}\quad\imp\quad\fermi\pars{x,y} = \half}
$$